# containarized shinyproxy very slow

Tags: java, r, docker, shiny, shinyproxy

I deployed a shinyapps using the stack: R, docker, and shinyproxy and so far the tools have been great with users happy. However am struggling a bit with load balancing so that I can scale and stop bothering users when I run updates on the solution.

With advise from https://www.shinyproxy.io/shinyproxy-containers/, I went through the process but using https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-config-examples/tree/master/02-containerized-docker-engine the containerized docker engine. My solution runs perfectly when I run java -jar shinyproxy-2.0.3.jar not containerised. **But now when I containerize it, it gets to be very very slow, infact even with internal networking active the containers crush when I try open them.**

At the moment I am just trying to test if containerizing shinyproxy can work without giving me issues but to a fail.

My Nginx configuration on the server

```
server {

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name qnumsolutions.com www.qnumsolutions.com;

        location / { 
       proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;

       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_read_timeout 600s;

       proxy_redirect    off;
       proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
       proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qnumsolutions.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qnumsolutions.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Shinyproxy application.yml

```
proxy:
  title: The Operational Intelligence Solution
  logo-url: http://qnum.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/OI-Solution-Icon.png
  landing-page: /
  heartbeat-rate: 100000
  heartbeat-timeout: 600000
  port: 8080
  authentication: simple 
  container-log-path: ./container-logs
  admin-groups: admin
  usage-stats-url: http://159.65.95.235:8086/write?db=shinyproxy_usagestats
  # Example: 'simple' authentication configuration
  users:
  - name: info@qnum.co.za
    password: prupr1.
    groups: admin
  docker:
    url: http://localhost:2375
    port-range-start: 20000
  specs:
  - id: OISolution1
    description: Application is designed to help organisations use advanced analytics to manage product visibility and variance
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e shiny::runApp('/root/hostedoi')"]
    container-image: oisolution
    container-volumes: ["/home/shiny/database:/mnt/persistent1"]
    access-groups: admin
  - id: OISolution2
    description: Application is designed to help organisations use advanced analytics to manage product visibility and variance
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e shiny::runApp('/root/hostedoi1')"]
    container-image: oisolution1
    container-volumes: ["/home/shiny/database:/mnt/persistent1"]
    access-groups: admin

logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

RUN mkdir -p /opt/shinyproxy/
RUN wget https://www.shinyproxy.io/downloads/shinyproxy-2.0.3.jar -O /opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar
COPY application.yml /opt/shinyproxy/application.yml

WORKDIR /opt/shinyproxy/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/shinyproxy/shinyproxy.jar"]
```

And lastly sudo docker ps yields

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
bc396c8bd26a        ois-shinyproxy      "java -jar /opt/shin…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   clever_beaver
```

Additional links I consulted:
https://fly.io/articles/load-balancing-a-fleet-of-docker-containers-using-fly/

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like there is a problem with your `usage-stats-url`. Maybe a firewall or something prevents ShinyProxy to reach this destination? I could reproduce this slow behavior, but it disappeared when I commented this line.

Besides that, there are some mistakes in your `application.yml` regarding Docker. I altered it a bit and managed to run it on my local machine with this configuration (`nginx.conf` and the Dockerfile were just slightly altered to fit my needs for `docker-compose`):

```
proxy:
  title: The Operational Intelligence Solution
  logo-url: http://qnum.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/OI-Solution-Icon.png
  landing-page: /
  heartbeat-rate: 100000
  heartbeat-timeout: 600000
  port: 8080
  authentication: simple 
  container-log-path: ./container-logs
  admin-groups: admin
  #usage-stats-url: http://159.65.95.235:8086/write?db=shinyproxy_usagestats
  # Example: 'simple' authentication configuration
  users:
  - name: info@qnum.co.za
    password: prupre35A21.
    groups: admin
  docker:
    internal-networking: true
  specs:
  - id: 01_hello
    display-name: Hello Application
    description: Application which demonstrates the basics of a Shiny app
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_01_hello()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    container-volumes: ["/tmp:/mnt/persistent1"]
    container-network: shinyproxy_slow_default
    access-groups: admin
  - id: 06_tabsets
    container-cmd: ["R", "-e", "shinyproxy::run_06_tabsets()"]
    container-image: openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo
    container-volumes: ["/tmp:/mnt/persistent1"]
    container-network: shinyproxy_slow_default
    access-groups: admin

logging:
  file:
    shinyproxy.log
```

I ran everything with `docker-compose`, see:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


  shinyproxy:
    image: sp_test
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./application.yml:/opt/shinyproxy/application.yml
```

Comment: I guess it was fatigue :). I did as advised above and also realized I had multiple spelling errors on my application.yml file. But managed to solve it thanks to your advise. I didnt use docker-compose though